# if $f_{e}$ is an even function and $f_{o}$ is an odd function, and $a > 0$ a constant, then: $\int_{-a}^{a}f_{e}(x)f_{o}(x)dx = 0$

Tags: calculus

I needed to prove or disaprove this: if $f_{e}$ is an even function and $f_{o}$ is an odd function, and $a > 0$ a constant, then: $$\int_{-a}^{a}f_{e}(x)f_{o}(x)dx = 0$$
I said that $f_{e}(x)f_{o}$ is an odd function and the integral of an odd function in a symmetric interval equals $0$.
Is it always true? What if one of the functions is not continous?

Answer (score 2):

If your two functions can be integrated, then the result holds, because $\int -f = -\int f$ no matter whether the function is continuous or not. It is one of the basic properties of integral.

So yes, in your particular case your argument was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Integration can also work even if we have finite number of discontinuities so  the result holds good even the function are discontinuous.

You can see it yourself by making your own even and odd functions with finite number of discontinuities and then evaluate the integral.